# How to test an observable in angular/jasmine when the observable next is called before the observable is returned, due to mocks

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, automated-tests

I have the following code

```js
login(user: string, pass: string): Observable<User> {
    const subject = new Subject<User>();

    this.authApi.authTokenPost(user, pass)
        .subscribe((token: OAuthAccessToken) => {
            this.tokenService.save(token);
            this.userApi.fetch()
                .subscribe((user: User) => {
                    subject.next(user);
                });
        }) // removed error handling for brevity

    return subject;
}
```

The problem of course is that I need two api calls, so back then I solved it by creating a new subject and returning that.

Now I'm writing the functional test..

```js
const user: User = {id: '1234'};

const authApi = jasmine.createSpyObj('AuthApi', ['authTokenPost']);
const tokenService = jasmine.createSpyObj('TokenService', ['save']);
const userApi = jasmine.createSpyObj('UserService', ['fetch']);

beforeEach(() => {    
    authApi.authTokenPost.and.returnValue(of(oauthAccessToken));
    userService.fetch.and.returnValue(of(user));

    authenticationService = new AuthService(authApi, tokenService, userApi);
});

it('should login', (done) => {
    authService.login('user', 'pass')
        .subscribe((user2) => {
            expect(user2).toEqual(user);
            done();
        })
});
```

The problem is that because of the mocks, the subscribe is called immediately, and therefore the `subject.next(user)` is called BEFORE the subject is even returned..

Does anyone know a good way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```js
authApi.authTokenPost.and.returnValue(of(oauthAccessToken).pipe(delay(0)));
```

By delaying any of the mock observables even for 0 microseconds, the call becomes async and therefore executes after returning the subject.